# ZK Hflex not working when using MVVM and include approaches

Tags: mvvm, include, zk

When I use Hflex property in a included page in a MVVM approach, it doesn't work.

The problem happens when I include some page inside another, and this page has components whose sizes are controlled by hflex property. I already tried to force the rendering of the components using invalidate on parent window load, or Clients.resize(component) when it is created inside the viewmodel class, but with no success. It just happens in this case: pages included in a MVVM scenario.

Here is a way to see the error: http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3bj6e5j/9-Hflex-not-working-with-include-pages-inside-div#source-1.
To see the problem, click in the "Open" label, then a combobox is shown. You can see that the size of the combobox is only updated after resizing the browser window or after clicking in the dropdown button

If I explicitly resize the browser window, then the components are correctly sized.

Could anyone give any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Here is a way to see the error: http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3bj6e5j/9-Hflex-not-working-with-include-pages-inside-div#source-1
To see the problem, click in the "Open" label, then a combobox is shown. You can see that the size of the combobox is only updated after resizing the browser window or after clicking in the dropdown button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the javascript who does the fault,

Let me explain more. First you set the src of the include correct.
This is before the javascript is called, and your div don't really have a width at that moment.
So it takes that size, what you see.
Then the javascript is called and and actually he show's the div, but with the rendered with of the include at that moment.
How can you fix it : use `zUtl.fireSized`.

[Here is your working fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3bj6e5j/12-Hflex-not-working-with-include-pages-inside-div).